# How to return the error validator laravel in string format

Tags: php, string, laravel, validation

In this example code:

```
 public function test(Request $request) {
    $rule = [
        'name' => 'required'
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rule);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->errors(); // <-- String format, not array
    }
    return $request->name;
}
```

I need that the error be a simple string.

Thanks

Comment: use `var_dump($validator->errors())` and select which error messages you want to display. Then concatenate them and return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
return $validator->errors()->first('name');
```